# iOS 8 - Lock view in position even with orientation change

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation, ios8

I am trying to create a locked view like the views in the Camera app. I want my view to stick to the same side of the screen regardless of orientation. I am using iOS 8 and the new Storyboard. In the past I have used `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, but I can't seem to get it's replacement working with `viewWillTransitionToSize:`.

In iOS 8, how do you keep a view in portrait location/orientation while the ViewController rotates?

Answer (score 0):

Just put inside the view controller you want to lock

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```